# Application crashes using EGL on Wayland inside a Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, egl, wayland

I am using an Apalis i.MX8QM module from Toradex. I installed Torizon, which is a Linux OS mantained by the manufacturer. It's designed to be used with debian-based Docker containers. They provide a container running Weston (Wayland + XWayland) to be able to render graphics.
In another container, I compiled OGRE3D graphics engine (source code: [www.github.com/OGRECave/ogre](https://www.github.com/OGRECave/ogre)) using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm64 torizon/wayland-base-vivante:2 AS base
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    apt-utils \
    && apt-mark hold dash && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-mark unhold dash \
    && apt-get clean && apt-get autoremove && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ARG ACCEPT_FSL_EULA=1
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    libwayland-client0 \
    libwayland-server0 \
    libgal-vivante1 \
    libvsc-vivante1 \
    libgbm-vivante1 \
    libegl-vivante1 \
    libgl-vivante1 \
    libglesv2-vivante1 \
    libglesv1-cm-vivante1 \
    libglslc-vivante1 \
    && apt-get clean && apt-get autoremove && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# Make sure the user can access DRM and video devices
RUN usermod -a -G video,render torizon
# UP TO HERE ITS CODE PROVIDED BY TORADEX 
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y git cmake gcc g++ make libxrandr-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libzip-dev libfreeimage-dev libpoco-dev libois-dev libzzip-0-13 libzzip-dev doxygen libcgal-dev libcppunit-dev libxt-dev libxaw7-dev pkg-config gdb x11-apps nano libsdl2-2.0 libegl-vivante1-dev
USER torizon
RUN cd /home/torizon/ && git clone https://github.com/OGRECave/ogre
RUN mkdir -p /home/torizon/ogre/bld && cd /home/torizon/ogre/bld && cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DOGRE_GLSUPPORT_USE_EGL=1 -DOGRE_BUILD_RENDERSYSTEM_GLES2=1 -DOGRE_BUILD_SAMPLES=1 -DOGRE_CONFIG_THREADS=0 -DOGRE_INSTALL_DOCS=0 -DOGRE_BUILD_PLUGIN_CG=0 -DOGRE_INSTALL_MEDIA=1 -DOGRE_BUILD_TOOLS=0 -DOGRE_BUILD_TESTS=0 -DOGRE_INSTALL_SAMPLES=1 ../
RUN cd /home/torizon/ogre/bld && make
USER root
RUN cd /home/torizon/ogre/bld && make install
```

The above container is ran with the following command (maybe some env variables aren't needed to really make this work):

```
docker run -e ACCEPT_FSL_EULA=1 -e X11_UNIX_SOCKET=/tmp/.X11-unix -e WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-0 -e XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR -e DISPLAY=:0 -it --rm --name=wayland-app --user=torizon -v /dev/dri:/dev/dri -v /dev/galcore:/dev/galcore -v /tmp:/tmp -v /run/:/run/ --device-cgroup-rule='c 199:* rmw' --device-cgroup-rule='c 226:* rmw' --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt seccomp=unconfined ogre-way-base-egl-j1
```

When I try to run the first sample compiled after the compilation of OGRE3D, I get some errors. I ran it with gdb to help debugging. Output is shown below:

```
torizon@0c2f3e5ed77f:~/ogre/bld/bin$ gdb SampleBrowser
GNU gdb (Debian 9.2-1) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "aarch64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from SampleBrowser...
(gdb) catch throw
Catchpoint 1 (throw)
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/torizon/ogre/bld/bin/SampleBrowser
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Creating resource group General
Creating resource group OgreInternal
Creating resource group OgreAutodetect
SceneManagerFactory for type 'DefaultSceneManager' registered.
Registering ResourceManager for type Material
Registering ResourceManager for type Mesh
Registering ResourceManager for type Skeleton
MovableObjectFactory for type 'ParticleSystem' registered.
ArchiveFactory for archive type FileSystem registered.
ArchiveFactory for archive type Zip registered.
ArchiveFactory for archive type EmbeddedZip registered.
DDS codec registering
ETC codec registering
ASTC codec registering
Registering ResourceManager for type HighLevelGpuProgram
Registering ResourceManager for type Compositor
MovableObjectFactory for type 'Entity' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'Light' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'BillboardSet' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'ManualObject' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'BillboardChain' registered.
MovableObjectFactory for type 'RibbonTrail' registered.
Loading library /home/torizon/ogre/bld/lib/RenderSystem_GLES2.so.1.12.12
Installing plugin: OpenGL ES 2.0 RenderSystem
OpenGL ES 2.x Rendering Subsystem created.
[New Thread 0xffffe5601170 (LWP 22)]
[New Thread 0xffffe4e00170 (LWP 23)]

Thread 1 "SampleBrowser" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000fffff6e6dbd0 in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000fffff6e6dbd0 in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000fffff69432f0 in wl_proxy_create_wrapper () from /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0
#2  0x0000fffff6ba1b50 in ?? () from /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so.1
#3  0x0000fffff6b94534 in eglInitialize () from /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so.1
#4  0x0000fffff6c7d694 in Ogre::EGLSupport::getGLDisplay (this=0xaaaaaab17b90) at /home/torizon/ogre/RenderSystems/GLSupport/src/EGL/OgreEGLSupport.cpp:65
#5  0x0000fffff6c618c4 in Ogre::X11EGLSupport::getGLDisplay (this=0xaaaaaab17b90) at /home/torizon/ogre/RenderSystems/GLSupport/src/EGL/X11/OgreX11EGLSupport.cpp:280
#6  0x0000fffff6c60ba4 in Ogre::X11EGLSupport::X11EGLSupport (this=0xaaaaaab17b90, profile=4) at /home/torizon/ogre/RenderSystems/GLSupport/src/EGL/X11/OgreX11EGLSupport.cpp:51
#7  0x0000fffff6c60b44 in Ogre::getGLSupport (profile=4) at /home/torizon/ogre/RenderSystems/GLSupport/src/EGL/X11/OgreX11EGLSupport.cpp:45
#8  0x0000fffff6c3d1c4 in Ogre::GLES2RenderSystem::GLES2RenderSystem (this=0xaaaaaab17180) at /home/torizon/ogre/RenderSystems/GLES2/src/OgreGLES2RenderSystem.cpp:178
#9  0x0000fffff6c3cb18 in Ogre::GLES2Plugin::install (this=0xaaaaaab17100) at /home/torizon/ogre/RenderSystems/GLES2/src/OgreGLES2Plugin.cpp:48
#10 0x0000fffff79c026c in Ogre::Root::installPlugin (this=0xaaaaaab00b20, plugin=0xaaaaaab17100) at /home/torizon/ogre/OgreMain/src/OgreRoot.cpp:1188
#11 0x0000fffff6c28bc4 in Ogre::dllStartPlugin () at /home/torizon/ogre/RenderSystems/GLES2/src/OgreGLES2EngineDll.cpp:41
#12 0x0000fffff79c064c in Ogre::Root::loadPlugin (this=0xaaaaaab00b20, pluginName="/home/torizon/ogre/bld/lib/RenderSystem_GLES2") at /home/torizon/ogre/OgreMain/src/OgreRoot.cpp:1237
#13 0x0000fffff79bf2c4 in Ogre::Root::loadPlugins (this=0xaaaaaab00b20, pluginsfile="./plugins.cfg") at /home/torizon/ogre/OgreMain/src/OgreRoot.cpp:973
#14 0x0000fffff79bc9ac in Ogre::Root::Root (this=0xaaaaaab00b20, pluginFileName="./plugins.cfg", configFileName="./ogre.cfg", logFileName="./ogre.log")
    at /home/torizon/ogre/OgreMain/src/OgreRoot.cpp:227
#15 0x0000fffff7f76d3c in OgreBites::ApplicationContextBase::createRoot (this=0xfffffffff238) at /home/torizon/ogre/Components/Bites/src/OgreApplicationContextBase.cpp:191
#16 0x0000fffff7f7663c in OgreBites::ApplicationContextBase::initApp (this=0xfffffffff238) at /home/torizon/ogre/Components/Bites/src/OgreApplicationContextBase.cpp:55
#17 0x0000aaaaaaab6b28 in OgreBites::SampleContext::go (this=0xfffffffff238, initialSample=0x0) at /home/torizon/ogre/Samples/Common/include/SampleContext.h:143
#18 0x0000aaaaaaab44e4 in main (argc=1, argv=0xfffffffff648) at /home/torizon/ogre/Samples/Browser/src/main.cpp:89
```

As we can see, it crashes at pthread_mutex_lock(), being called from libwayland-client.

Just before calling eglInitialize() (exactly in [this](https://github.com/OGRECave/ogre/blob/94d6856c1aa2eead5326e7e3f625828d3599f551/RenderSystems/GLSupport/src/EGL/OgreEGLSupport.cpp#L65) line of code), the arguments values are:

```
(gdb) step
65              if (eglInitialize(mGLDisplay, &mEGLMajor, &mEGLMinor) == EGL_FALSE)
(gdb) print mGLDisplay
$3 = (EGLDisplay) 0xaaaaaab16180
(gdb) print *mEGLMajor
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
(gdb) print mEGLMajor
$4 = 0
(gdb) print mEGLMinor
$5 = 0
```

I searched in the Internet but I can't find any solution suitable to my situation, and I don't know how to proceed in order to try to solve this.

Any information is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue building ogre using our Visual studio code extension, so things may be a bit different (I used cross-complication and have one container to build and one to run the app).
First I changed the build configuration to remove some renderers, this helps keeping dependencies simpler.
Those are my defines in cmake:

```
    "OGRE_GLSUPPORT_USE_EGL":1,
    "OGRE_BUILD_RENDERSYSTEM_GL":0,
    "OGRE_BUILD_RENDERSYSTEM_GL3PLUS":0,
    "OGRE_BUILD_RENDERSYSTEM_TINY":0,
    "OGRE_BUILD_RENDERSYSTEM_GLES2":1,
    "OGRE_BUILD_SAMPLES":1,
    "OGRE_CONFIG_THREADS": 0,
    "OGRE_INSTALL_DOCS":0,
    "OGRE_BUILD_PLUGIN_CG":0,
    "OGRE_INSTALL_MEDIA":1,
    "OGRE_BUILD_TOOLS":0,
    "OGRE_BUILD_TESTS":0,
    "OGRE_INSTALL_SAMPLES":1
```

I also added a post-install command to make to fix the installation paths from my local folder to the one I use on the device (/ogre).
At the end of CMakeList.txt I added:

```
install (SCRIPT "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/PostInstall.cmake")
```

And this is PostInstall.cmake:

```
message("Post install script")

execute_process(COMMAND bash "-c" "sed -i s+/workspaces/ogre/appconfig_0/work/ogre+/ogre+g ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/share/OGRE/*.cfg"
    )
```

For build I use this dockerfile:

```
FROM torizon/debian-cross-toolchain-arm64:2-bullseye

RUN HOLD_PKGS='libdrm-common libdrm-amdgpu1:arm64 libdrm2:arm64' \
    && apt-get -y update \
    && apt-get -y upgrade \
    && for P in $HOLD_PKGS ; do \
    echo ${P}=$(apt-cache show $P | sed -r -e '/^Version:/!d' -e 's/.* //' -e '/toradex/d' -e 'q') ; \
    done | xargs -r apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    && apt-mark hold $HOLD_PKGS \
    && apt-get clean && apt-get autoremove && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# commands that should be run before installing packages (ex: to add a feed or keys)


# your regular RUN statements here
# Install required packages
RUN apt-get -q -y update \
    && apt-get -q -y install gdb-multiarch procps rsync openssh-client\
    libwayland-dev:arm64 \
    libgbm-vivante1-dev:arm64 libegl-vivante1-dev:arm64 libglesv2-vivante1-dev:arm64 libxrandr-dev:arm64  libzip-dev:arm64 libfreeimage-dev:arm64 libpoco-dev:arm64 libois-dev:arm64 libzzip-dev:arm64 doxygen libcgal-dev:arm64 libcppunit-dev:arm64 libxt-dev:arm64 libxaw7-dev:arm64\
    \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

(you can add commands to clone the code, apply the changes and build it)

This is the dockerfile I use to run the application:

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm64 torizon/wayland-base:2
          
# Make sure we don't get notifications we can't answer during building.
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive"

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/ogre/lib OGRE_PLUGIN_DIR=/ogre/lib/OGRE

# commands that should be run before installing packages (ex: to add a feed or keys)


# your regular RUN statements here
# Install required packages
RUN if [ ! -z "libxt6 libxaw7 libzzip-0-13 libxrandr2" ]; then \
    apt-get -q -y update \
    && apt-get -q -y install libxt6 libxaw7 libzzip-0-13 libxrandr2 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* ; \
    fi

# commands that should be run after all packages have been installed (RUN/COPY/ADD)



COPY work/ogre /ogre


USER torizon

WORKDIR /ogre

# commands that will run on the target (ENTRYPOINT or CMD)
CMD /ogre/bin/SampleBrowser
```

In this way I was able to run the application without crashes.
There is an issue with the mouse cursor that is not visible when over openGL surfaces.
I used Verdin iMX8MM because I don't have an Apalis IMX8 available ATM, but the platforms should be similar (imx8 and vivante drivers for the GPU).

If you want to try building this with our IDE extension I can share my changes to ogre master branch, but debugging this issue I found a problem in our own extension and it will take a few weeks before we could publish an update.
Sorry for the issue.

Comment: This is the command line used to run your application, provided that weston container is already up and running.

Comment: docker run --device-cgroup-rule 'c 199:* rmw'  --device-cgroup-rule 'c 226:* rmw'  --volume /tmp:/tmp --volume /dev/dri:/dev/dri --volume /dev/galcore:/dev/galcore <your image name>

Comment: Hi Valter, thank you for the detailed answer. It helps me a lot. I never used before the IDE extension, I thought I had to use it to develop the application once I had Ogre compiled, but I see I was wrong.
I wanted to ask, is there any special modification that I have to do in the extension to build this? I tried several times with no sucess, but I feel it's my fault because I still don't understand the workflow completely. When I try to build the debug container you shared, for example, It says it couldn't find libxdamage

Comment: There was an issue with 64-bit builds for Vivante platforms.
If you download the latest early-access release of the extension (if you are using the stable one you have to first remove it to use early access) you should be able to build ogre and run the sample.
Here you can find the changes I made compared to current master branch of Ogre:
https://gist.github.com/VMinute/512320e393108669ad32cd131199aae2

Comment: Hi Valter, I compiled Ogre3D as you suggested, but I found out that GPU wasn't being used for rendering. In my attempts to fix that, I found out that the base container that vscode extension produces is based on torizon/wayland-base instead of torizon/wayland-base-vivante (isn't that an error?). So I installed all the libraries needed for the GPU (the same that wayland-base-vivante Dockerfile installs), but I end up with a little bit different error than before, again related to libwayland-client (I think). The real question is, should I post this in Toradex forums or should we keep ...

Comment: Talking here? 
This is the gdb backtrace
https://gist.github.com/tomasayi/8c44096bb9ca5407f18d55f38632e436

Container is run as
docker run --device-cgroup-rule 'c 199:* rmw' --device-cgroup-rule 'c 226:* rmw' --volume /tmp:/tmp --volume /dev/dri:/dev/dri --volume /dev/galcore:/dev/galcore <container-name>

Comment: You are right about the base container.
It's a good idea to post this in the community.